# Why bind.('paste' with "if" must be done twice to be active

Tags: jquery, regex

I use a script to detect url in text when someone paste a text with URL.

So I use this script:

```
$("#post").bind('paste', function(){

   var $ptext = $('textarea#post').val();
   var regexText = /^http:\/\/www$/;
   if(regexText.test($ptext))
   {
    alert('URL DETECTED');
   }
});
```

But when I reload the page and I paste the text for the first time the script does nothing
and I'm forced to repaste the text again, and then the script works.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Use the contextual `$(this)` rather than forcing to jQuery to look up the same selector again (`$('textarea#post')`)

Comment: When are you executing this piece of code?

Comment: ok.. have you tried to debug it? is `$ptext` ok? how do you know that `if` fails? what do you do inside? do you log to the console?

Comment: if regex is true then send $.get else do nothning

Comment: please do the whole debugging. what is send $.get? a simple console.log will do it..

Comment: I don't know why, but for some reason `.bind()` needs a `setTimeout(function(){ //now do the textarea val() call;}, 100);` in order to access the updated paste event...but if you use `.on()` instead, it will work without the setTimeout call..

Comment: [here's a working example showing how to achieve this in either scenario](http://jsfiddle.net/NRNDe/)

Comment: Ohgodwhy, THIS IS WORKIN THANKS ALOT, setTimout solving all,

Comment: Is your code in $(document).ready(function() {});

Comment: what if he doesn't use paste? I'm not sure binding to paste is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but for some reason .bind() needs a setTimeout(function(){ //now do the textarea val() call;}, 100); in order to access the updated paste event...but if you use .on() instead, it will work without the setTimeout call

[here's a working example showing how to achieve this in either scenario](http://jsfiddle.net/NRNDe/)

thanks to @Ohgodwhy